# C - Execvp + Shell

Tags: c, shell, exec

I am having some difficulty with my program right now. I am trying to write a program that runs shell commands, however I believe I am using execvp wrong and passing in the wrong arguments. When I type ls it says cannot access, there is no such file or directory? I have looked at lots of examples and have tried to mimic them, but to no prevail.

Also my exit check is completely skipped over and I do not believe the "wait" function is waiting.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
  char input[1024];
  char *arguments[100];
  char* directive;
  int doExit = 0;

  while(doExit != 1){
  printf("\n");
  printf("Welcome to myShell\n");
  printf("? : ");

  fgets(input, 1024, stdin);

  char *token;
  int count = 1;
  int argsCount = 1; 

  token = strtok(input, " "); 

  while(token != NULL){ 
    if(count == 1){
        directive = strdup(token);
        arguments[0] = strdup(directive); 
        ++count;
    }
    else{
        arguments[argsCount] = strdup(token); 
        ++argsCount;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  arguments[argsCount] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", directive);

  if(strcmp(arguments[0], "exit") == 0){
    doExit = 1;
    exit(1);
  }
  pid_t pid = fork(); // create child
  int status;
  int i = 0;
  printf("Arguments:\n");
  for(i =0; i < sizeof(arguments) && arguments[i] != NULL; ++i){
    printf("%s\n", arguments[i]);
  }

  if(pid >= 0){
    if(pid == 0){
      printf("I am the child.\n");

      printf("%s\n", directive);
      int result = execvp(directive, arguments);    
      if(result < 0){
        printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    else if(pid >= 0){
      printf("I am the parent.\n");

        while (wait(&status) != pid){
            ;
        }
    }
  }
  else{
     printf("Error: Fork was unsuccessful.\n");
     exit(1);
  }

  printf("\n");
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the same program you posted 2 hours ago in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157317/c-shell-program

Comment: It is good that you do the diagnostic printing; you should probably do it before you fork, though. You should unclutter your logic, too. There are three cases: error, child, parent. You should have `if (pid < 0) { ...error... } else if (pid == 0) { ...child... } else { ...parent... }`.

Comment: Perhaps >.>  <.<    ... however I am still stuck after a couple hours later. My main issue when I posted that was why execvp wasn't working for me. No one mentioned why.

Comment: @Barmar: nearly, but not quite. This has some mis-placed diagnostic printing.  The other question is deleted, anyway.

Comment: You're putting `"ls\n"` in `directive`, because your `strtok()` only uses space as a delimiter, not newline.

Comment: You know the first rule of debugging: print data. The second rule of debugging is: print data so you can see what's wrong.  In this case, the first thing I did was change lines like `printf("%s\n", directive);` into `printf("Cmd <<%s>>\n", directive);` so that when I saw (a minute or two after Barmar did) that the output when I typed `ls` included the newline in the string, the rest of the problem was obvious.

Comment: Thank you. But now when I type ls -la the arguments[1] = ls -la and execvp returns -1 giving me an error.. I thought the arguments had to be seperated? so arguments[1] =ls   arguments[2] = -la and so forth? I will try  printf("Cmd <<%s>>\n", directive);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
token = strtok(input, " \n\t");
```

and:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
```

so that the newline at the end of `input` will be treated as a token delimiter, not included in the token.

Another error:

```
i < sizeof(arguments)
```

should be:

```
i < sizeof(arguments)/sizeof(*arguments)
```

since `sizeof` returns the size in bytes, not the number of elements in the array.

I suggest you change your diagnostic printfs to put a character around the string, like:

```
printf("'%s'\n", arguments[i]);
```

This way, you'll be able to tell if there are extra characters like newline included in the argument.

Comment: Ah thanks. That fixed my issue with just using ls, but now when I try to run ls -la it says the arguments at argument[1] is "ls la" and execvp returns -1 and fails.

Comment: You need to specify blank (and tab) and newline, not just blank or just newline, as the delimiter – twice.  Do you really lose the `-`? I don't!  I also changed the `fgets()` line to `if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == 0) break;` to handle EOF sanely.  Not everyone types `exit` to exit from a shell.

Comment: Ah sorry that was a typo. Alright I'll play around with it. I've had my head buried in ExtJS at work all day and C is not my thing.. Thanks for the help.